# In Lazarus, how to defocus TCustomControl descendents (cross-platform)?

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

I am using Lazarus 2.3.0, FPC 3.3.1

A control will get focus when you put it on a form, by default. Lets say you have a TMemo (implemented via Widgetset) on a TForm. When the form is active, the memo will get focus. So, how to defocus the memo so the form will be shown with no focused control at all? You may ask "Why?". Just for learning, I am trying to understand why I can't do it (or should not do it).

Right now I tried the following alternatives with no success on Linux:

```
// Form1 OnActive event
DefocusControl(Memo1, False);
DefocusControl(Memo1, True);
Form1.ActiveControl := nil;
```

PS.: It is worth noting that right now there is a 7 year issue opened on a related topic here:

https://gitlab.com/freepascal.org/lazarus/lazarus/-/issues/25396

Answer (score 1):

Here is the workaround that I use. You can disable TabStop property of every control on your form through Object Inspector or dynamically with:

```
for i := 0 to Form1.ComponentCount-1 do
  if Form1.Components[i] is TWinControl then
    (Form1.Components[i] as TWinControl).TabStop := False;  
Form1.ActiveControl := nil;
```

`DefocusControl` when used in `FormActivate` doesn't work for me at all, it does nothing. I guess it's just a bug. `Removing` (second parameter in `DefocusControl`) is not even implemented in Lazarus.

Comment: Hi @T-Khan, thank you for your answer. I am afraid to say that it does not work on Linux, I tested it with a TMemo, TRichMemo and TButton.